# VPN disconnects after connecting in windows 10 v2004

Tags: windows-10, networking, vpn, windows-10-v2004

I have used my VPN connection on previous version of Windows 10 successfully.
But after upgrading to current latest update which is 2004 my VPN connection disconnects right after connecting.

I have to login to my account in order to have access to internet after connecting to this VPN and I think this causes the problem, because Windows thinks there is not internet connection and automatically disconnects VPN (My be I am wrong).

I searched the internet how to keep my VPN connection alive but no successful solution found.
for example [this](https://www.miqrogroove.com/blog/2011/windows-vpn-keep-alive/) blog post suggests having a script to check if connection is lost and connect again.

And some details about my VPN that may be helpful:

[image: VPN Security Tab]